# OpenLayers 2 mousePosition projection on the fly

Tags: openlayers-2, mouse-position

I'm displaying coordinates in epsg:3857 using `ol.control.MousePosition()` with OSM.
I'd like to convert these on the fly in another epsg:2154.

I call in the header :

```html
<script> src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.2.2/proj4-src.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then my html :

```js
var map = new OpenLayers.Map({
        div: "map",
        projection: "EPSG:3857",
        controls:[
                new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({'ascending':false}),
                new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine({
                    'geodesic': "true"
                }),
                 new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
                 new OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults(),
                 new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition(
                     {displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:2154")}
                 )
                ]
        });
```

but it doesn't seem to work : coordinates are false, even negative where they shouldn't.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Set your "displayProjection" when creating the map, then simply add the MousePosition control:

```
var options = {
        projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
        displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:2154"),
        units: "m",
        numZoomLevels: 18,
        maxResolution: 156543.0339,
        minResolution: "auto",
        minExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-1, -1, 1, 1),
        maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.34, -20037508.34,
                                         20037508.34, 20037508.34)
    };
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', options)
map.addControl( new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition() );
```

Comment: Thx. 
I m trying to use ol3. Maybe I can mix with ol2x ?
Cause i can't "convert" the code you wrote in ol3 :/
thx btw

Comment: Leehan, this code works just fine in OpenLayers3.

Comment: ok thx
Will try asap.

Comment: I used Openlayers2 and updated first post like you said.