# Using OSGB (ESPG: 27700) projection in Openlayers with MousePosition

Tags: openlayers-2, coordinate-system, mouse-position

I am trying to display Ordnance Survey Grid references (ESPG:27700) on a set of BaseMaps with the MousePosition control.

From looking through the OpenLayers samples, and this forum, samples I have managed to figure out most of the code that is needed. I understand that you need to reference the projection and include the proj4.js reference library.  But I think I am missing something as I can get coordinates in ESPG: 4326 and 900913, but not 27700, if I set the "displayProjection:" option accordingly.

Please see my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Sample Map</title>
    <script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
 <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/proj4js/2.2.1/proj4.js"></script>

<script> 
proj4.defs("EPSG:27700", '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717' +
' +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs');

OpenLayers.Projection.get('EPSG:27700').setExtent([0, 0, 800000, 1400000]);
OpenLayers.Projection.get('EPSG:27700').setWorldExtent([-10, 49, 6, 63]);
OpenLayers.Projection.get('EPSG:27700').setGlobal(false);
OpenLayers.Projection.get('EPSG:27700').setGetPointResolution(function
(resolution) { return resolution; });

    var map;

    function init(){
        var geographic = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326');
        var mercator = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:900913');
        var osgb = new OpenLayers.Projection('ESPG:27700');

        map = new OpenLayers.Map("map",{projection: mercator} );

// Add The layer swticher     
        map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());

// Add A Scale Bar

       map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine());

    // Add Mouse Cursor Posistion
            map.addControl(
                        new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition({
                        prefix: '<a target="_blank" ' +
                        'href="http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/27700/">' +
                        'EPSG:27700</a> coordinates: ',
                        separator: ' | ',
                        numDigits: 2,
                        displayProjection: 'EPSG:27700',
                        emptyString: 'Mouse is not over map.'
                        })
                        );
        // Add the Open StreetMaps Layer
        var OSM = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM( "Simple OSM Map");


        //Add the Google Hybird Layer
        var ghyb = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
        "Google Hybrid",
        {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,  visibility: false}
        );

       // Add the Google Satellite Layer
        var gsat = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
        "Google Satellite",
        {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE}
        );

        // Add The Layers into the Map
        map.addLayers([OSM, ghyb, gsat]);

        //Use a converter to convert LonLat
        var locationCentre= new OpenLayers.LonLat(-2, 49).transform( new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326'), new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:900913') );

        // Pan the Map to the locationCentre Variable with the zoom level at 5
        map.setCenter(locationCentre, 5);
        }

</script>
```

Comment: Does this [Q&A](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103606/openlayers-3-mouseposition-projection-on-the-fly) help?

Comment: Hi thanks for this, but unfortunately this has not worked!

Answer (score 1):

According to an answer from Andreas Hocevar you have to add a wrapper before you load projections from spatialreference.org:

```
<script>
    window.Proj4js = {
        Proj: function(code) { return proj4(Proj4js.defs[code]); },
        defs: proj4.defs,
        transform: proj4
    };
</script>
```

http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/OL-2-13-1-latest-Proj4js-td5081636.html

I gave it a try in jsfiddle and it seems to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/expedio/9tmq4auk/